# Axon commands on read model

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon, axon-framework

We are currently using axon framework with hikaricp  as data source pooling system. We are facing pool exhausting issues from time to time and we have a theory:

- To update our read models we use the command bus to send UpdateEntityViewCommand.
- As the command bus starts a transaction using the primary transaction manager (the write one) it acquires a connection from the write pool
- On the handler, we open an inner transaction using a connection from the read pool, thus blocking the outer one.

This seems to exhaust the pools under some conditions. The question is: should we stop using the command bus to update our read models? Is *appropiate* to have two buses( one for write and one for read?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consider adding code snippets where you are facing problems for better understanding and a quick response from community.

Comment: I am not completely sure about the transactions you are using. Are you doing it manually? AFAIK, Axon will take care of that for you. If you are configuring those manually, can you share some code and light on that?

Answer (score 1):

Axon's intent with the separation of Commands, Events, and Queries, is in general to support CQRS within your system. This means you would introduce dedicated Command Models and Query Models, which respectively *only* receive Command and Query messages.

The Query Models are typically also referred to as Projections or Read Models.

It is this combination of ideas Axon is normally used for which makes your question a bit vague. Or, perchance, you are using it differently than normally intended.
That Axon supports CQRS through this approach, does not necessitate that you do CQRS within your set up as well, by the way.

At any note, it would be good too (as also stated in the comments):

- Include code snippets of the message handlers when these prove useful
- Give some deeper insight in your configuration
- Whether you aim to use the CQRS pattern in your application, yes or no

Completely separate from this, I can give some guidance on how Axon deals with transactions. **Every** message inside an Axon application will start a so-called "Unit of Work". It is the `UnitOfWork` (UoW for short) that will start a transaction. This means that no matter if you use commands, events or queries, Axon will have started that transaction for you already.

Taking this a step further, this also means that *whatever* you do inside a message handling function (thus the `@CommandHandler`, `@EventHandler` and `@QueryHandler` annotated methods) will always already have an active transaction running. That for example defines that you do not have to include your own transaction management inside a message handling function, with for example the `@Transactional` annotation.

Concluding, I am guessing you might be mixing some concepts. This can obviously happen, so no worries there; that's what SO is for. Next to this though, you thus do not have to start your own transaction inside any message handling function, as you already have an active transaction at that point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your response Steven. Sorry to not be more clear at the original question. Our main difference and what we believe is the source of this problem is that we have two different pools ( one for the read model, another one for write model ) Given this, we need to annotate any read model modifying method signaling that we need to use the read model pool.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for coming back to this. The way to separate these threads pools using Axon specifics, is by registering distinct `TransactionManager` instances. The `EventProcessingConfigurer` has a `registerTransactionManager` method for this, which allows you to define a different pool as well. That means you will no longer require the `@Transactional` annotation, as Axon's Unit of Work will take care of it.

Comment: Furher more, what's unclear to me is whether I need to update my answer to suit your problem space. Any pointers you might give me what you are exactly looking for?